# notify-send infinite notification

Tags: bash, scripts, notification, notify-send

I made a short script to notify myself when my battery is below 25% and above 75%. I'm using notify-send to send notifications and play alert sound as to notify the user of the event. The problem I'm facing is that I want to send a persistent notification with the alert sound playing constantly. Like if the battery goes above 75% and the AC is still plugged the notification must be persistent with the alert sound playing constantly till the user unplugs the AC power. Similarly, if the battery power goes below 25% the scripts does the same.

Problem I'm having is that with notify-send is that the notifications are stacked up over the previous notifications and I can't figure out that how can I show a persistent notification with a constant alert sound playing in the background.

Image and code is attached below as to better understand my problem.

[image: notifications send by notify-send]

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do
        export DISPLAY=:0.0
        battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
        ac_adapter=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)
    if [ "$ac_adapter" = "on" ]; then
                if [ $battery_level -ge 75 ]; then              #check if the battery level is over 75%
            while :
                do
                notify-send -u critical "Please unplug your AC adapter" "Battery level: ${battery_level}% (charged above 75%)" -i battery-full-charged; play /home/ali/Music/alarm.wav
                sleep 1
                ac_adapter=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)
                if [ "$ac_adapter" = "off" ]; then
                    break              #Abandon the loop.
                fi
                done    

             fi
        else
                if [ $battery_level -lt 25 ]; then              #check if the battery level is less than 25%
            while :
                do
                    notify-send -u critical "Please plug your AC adapter" "Battery level: ${battery_level}% (charge below 25%)" -i battery-caution; play /home/ali/Music/alarm.wav
                sleep 1
                ac_adapter=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)
                if [ "$ac_adapter" = "on" ]; then
                    break              #Abandon the loop.
                fi
                done    

             fi
        fi
      sleep 1                                             #wait for 1 seconds before checking again

    done
```

Comment: Battery level is showing 47% in notification because I used dummy data to invoke the script as to test it.

Comment: Notify send is not meant to show persistent message. Use a gtk window popup that can -or can't- be dismissed.